# How to remove search and refresh fields from W2UI grid toolbar?

Tags: javascript, html, w2ui

The W2UI Grid component has an option to turn on a toolbar.  Unfortunately it contains two fields that I don't want and take up space that I don't have.  The two fields are the search and refresh.  You can see them [here](http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#!grid/grid-17).

How do you turn them off?  I've tried removing the "searches" items from the w2grid definition options, but yet the search field remains.  Has anyone figured out how to hide those two fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those toolbar elements can be hidden via `grid.show`.

To remove the search drop-down set `toolbarSearch` to false.

To remove the search input field set `toolbarInput` to false.

To remove the refresh button set `toolbarReload` to false.

Here's the modified `show` property based on the demo you've linked:

```
    show: { 
        toolbar: true,
        footer: true,
        toolbarAdd: true,
        toolbarDelete: true,
        toolbarSave: true,
        toolbarEdit: true,
        toolbarSearch: false,
        toolbarInput: false,
        toolbarReload: false,
    },
```

`grid.show` documentation can be found here: http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2grid.show

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g5ebyqdv/

Comment: Thanks again Mike!  Sorry I missed the docs.  I had been focusing on the demos and their source and didn't notice the Docs tab.  I'm very impressed with how W2UI is architected.  Kudos!